# Can a Page Number of a given virtual address be equals to 0 in memory mapping?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, mapping, computer-science, cpu-architecture

Say you were given a Page Size of 6 KB (6144 bytes) and a Virtual Address value of 2309 using the formula: Page = Virtual Address / Page size, which is 0,376 or just 0 is this possible in a real-world situation, thanks in advance?

Comment: A non-power-of-2 page size seems extremely unlikely.  That means the hardware needs to actually divide / modulo to get page / offset instead of just taking the low address bits as the offset and high address bits as the page.  (Unless your hardware uses trinary instead of binary logic?  But no, your page size has multiple prime factors, so it's not a power of 3.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pages are integer entities, so there are consecutive page addresses from 0 to maximum number of pages, identical to virtual addresses that exists from 0 to maximum memory size (ignoring canonicality) - Virtual address 2309 is the byte number 2309 in page number 0.

Having said that, virtual page doesn't have to be present and doesn't have to be mapped to physical address, so it is not necessary possible to access any random address in the virtual address range.

Comment: I had a totally different preconception, I'm relatively new to the subject thank you for the great insights, @Haim Cohen.